# What's wrong with my ostream overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am a student. I am currently learning c++ operator overloading but I can't seem to find any problem with my code but there is no output for the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Float {
private:
    float data;
public:
    Float(float data = 0)
      : data(data) {}
    friend Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b);
    friend Float operator-(const Float& a, const Float& b);
    friend Float operator*(const Float& a, const Float& b);
    friend Float operator/(const Float& a, const Float& b);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Float a);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Float a) {
    out << a.data;
    return out;
}
Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a + b);
}
Float operator-(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a - b);
}
Float operator*(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a * b);
}
Float operator/(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a / b);
}
int main() {
    Float f1, f2;
    f1 = 2.5;
    f2 = 3.1;
    cout << "f1+f2: "
         << (f1 + f2) << endl
         << "f1-f2: "
         << (f1 - f2) << endl
         << "f1*f2: "
         << (f1 * f2) << endl
         << "f1/f2: "
         << (f1 / f2) << endl;
}
```

I tried lots of variations like putting const and more on the overloading part but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `Float(a + b)` is infinite recursion, you want `Float(a.data + b.data)`.

Comment: In `Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b)`, you do `return Float(a + b);`.  What are the types of `a` and `b`?  What operator would they call to add them together?  See the issue?

Comment: @rawrex `endl` does more, but it cannot explain why no output is produced here

Comment: Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a + b);
}
That will keep calling itself for ever.. you need to do
Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a.data + b.data);
}
all your operators need to be fixed.

Comment: @rawrex: flushing from `std::endl` is even better for beginners, as they are no "missing output" before bugged line.

Comment: @Jarod42: To be fair, terminal output should be line-buffered by default anyway...

Comment: This question is not off topic and completely reproduce-able. why was it closed?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Float {
private:
    float data;
public:
    Float(float data = 0)
      : data(data) {}
    friend Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b); 
    friend Float operator-(const Float& a, const Float& b); 
    friend Float operator*(const Float& a, const Float& b); 
    friend Float operator/(const Float& a, const Float& b); 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Float a); 
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Float a) {
    out << a.data;
    return out;
}
Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a.data + b.data);
}
Float operator-(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a.data - b.data);
}
Float operator*(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a.data * b.data);
}
Float operator/(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a.data / b.data);
}
int main() {
    Float f1, f2; 
    f1 = 2.5;
    f2 = 3.1;
    cout << "f1+f2: "
         << (f1 + f2) << endl
         << "f1-f2: "
         << (f1 - f2) << endl
         << "f1*f2: "
         << (f1 * f2) << endl
         << "f1/f2: "
         << (f1 / f2) << endl;
}
```

The reason for this is that your original implementation for your operators looked like this:

```
Float operator+(const Float& a, const Float& b) {
    return Float(a + b);
}
```

But `a` and `b` are of type `Float`. which will call the `operator +` with `(Float, Float)` as arguments which is itself. which will call itself again and again until it crashes.

Comment: Thanks everyone i found out the problem from your cmments i guess c++ should have it's own way of making it an error code